# No Output From Some Git Commands C# Process

Tags: c#, git

Only some commands produce any output at all for standard output and standard error. In addition, I've read that calling ReadToEnd on both streams may potentially cause a deadlock? If anybody knows of a safer way to read the streams that would be much appreciated. Below is how I am running the process and getting the output. The problem is that for fetch the output is empty (the fetching command does work just doesn't provide output), but not for other commands like pull.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi= new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.FileName = "git.exe";
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.WorkingDirectory = workingDir;
psi.Arguments = "fetch -v";

Process fetchProcess = new Process();
fetchProcess.StartInfo = psi;
fetchProcess.Start();
string err = "";
string stdout = "";
//Both standard error and stdout are empty. But if argument is 
// a git pull, then standard error and output are not empty.
using (StreamReader myOutput = fetchProcess.StandardOutput) {
    stdout = myOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
using (StreamReader myError = fetchProcess.StandardError) {
    err= myError .ReadToEnd();
}
fetchProcess.WaitForExit();
fetchProcess.Close();
```

Anyway to make sure the fetch results are outputted?

Comment: git fetch normally outputs nothing if nothing is found to be fetched on the remote

Comment: `git fetch --verbose` could be what you need?

Comment: You are correct, I had tried git fetch -v but that had not worked. --verbose fixed it, thank you.